# Optimización de vistas derivadas de otras vistas creadas a partir de varias uniones

Tags: mysql, sql, optimización

Estoy trabajando con 3 vistas 2 de ellas están creadas a partir de varias uniones y la tercera une la primera y la segunda con un left join.

**Primera Vista**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW proveedores_movimientos_base_v AS

SELECT
  c.cuotprov_empr_codigo         base_empr_codigo,
  c.cuotprov_sucu_codigo         base_sucu_codigo,
  c.cuotprov_movi_codigo         base_movi_codigo, 
  a.antiprov_prov_codigo         base_prov_codigo,
  cue_ant.cuen_mon_codigo        base_mon_codigo, 
  c.cuotprov_secuencia           base_cuotprov_secuencia_base,
  c.cuotprov_opertipo_codigo     base_opertipo_codigo_base,
  c.cuotprov_operacion_numero    base_operacion_numero_base,
  a.antiprov_fecha_documento     base_fecha_base,
  a.antiprov_recibo_numero       base_comprobante_base,
  c.cuotprov_monto               base_monto_base,
  a.antiprov_cotizacion          base_cotizacion_base,
  a.antiprov_situacion           base_situacion
FROM cuotas_proveedores c
INNER JOIN anticipos_proveedores a
ON a.antiprov_numero = c.cuotprov_operacion_numero
and a.antiprov_empr_codigo = c.cuotprov_empr_codigo
and a.antiprov_opertipo_codigo = c.cuotprov_opertipo_codigo
and c.cuotprov_movi_codigo = 5
LEFT JOIN cuentas cue_ant
ON cue_ant.cuen_codigo = a.antiprov_cuen_codigo
AND cue_ant.cuen_empr_codigo = a.antiprov_empr_codigo

UNION ALL

SELECT
  c.cuotprov_empr_codigo         base_empr_codigo,
  c.cuotprov_sucu_codigo         base_sucu_codigo,
  c.cuotprov_movi_codigo         base_movi_codigo,
  com.comp_prov_codigo           base_prov_codigo,
  com.comp_mon_codigo            base_mon_codigo,
  c.cuotprov_secuencia           base_cuotprov_secuencia_base,
  c.cuotprov_opertipo_codigo     base_opertipo_codigo_base,
  c.cuotprov_operacion_numero    base_operacion_numero_base,
  com.comp_fecha_documento       base_fecha_base,
  com.comp_comprobante           base_comprobante_base,
  c.cuotprov_monto               base_monto_base,
  com.comp_cotizacion            base_cotizacion_base,
  com.comp_situacion             base_situacion
FROM cuotas_proveedores c
INNER JOIN compras com
ON com.comp_numero = c.cuotprov_operacion_numero
and com.comp_empr_codigo = c.cuotprov_empr_codigo
and com.comp_opertipo_codigo = c.cuotprov_opertipo_codigo
and com.comp_movi_codigo = c.cuotprov_movi_codigo
and com.comp_opertipo_codigo = 2

UNION ALL

SELECT
  c.cuotprov_empr_codigo         base_empr_codigo,
  c.cuotprov_sucu_codigo         base_sucu_codigo,
  c.cuotprov_movi_codigo         base_movi_codigo,
  e.egre_prov_codigo             base_prov_codigo,
  e.egre_mon_codigo              base_mon_codigo,
  c.cuotprov_secuencia           base_cuotprov_secuencia_base,
  c.cuotprov_opertipo_codigo     base_opertipo_codigo_base,
  c.cuotprov_operacion_numero    base_operacion_numero_base,
  e.egre_fecha_documento         base_fecha_base,
  e.egre_comprobante             base_comprobante_base,
  c.cuotprov_monto               base_monto_base,
  e.egre_cotizacion              base_cotizacion_base,
  e.egre_situacion               base_situacion
FROM cuotas_proveedores c
INNER JOIN egresos e
ON e.egre_numero = c.cuotprov_operacion_numero
and e.egre_empr_codigo = c.cuotprov_empr_codigo
and e.egre_opertipo_codigo = c.cuotprov_opertipo_codigo
and e.egre_movi_codigo = c.cuotprov_movi_codigo

UNION ALL

SELECT
  c.cuotprov_empr_codigo         base_empr_codigo,
  c.cuotprov_sucu_codigo         base_sucu_codigo,
  c.cuotprov_movi_codigo         base_movi_codigo,
  n.ncreci_prov_codigo           base_prov_codigo,
  n.ncreci_mon_codigo            base_mon_codigo,
  c.cuotprov_secuencia           base_cuotprov_secuencia_base,
  c.cuotprov_opertipo_codigo     base_opertipo_codigo_base,
  c.cuotprov_operacion_numero    base_operacion_numero_base,
  n.ncreci_fecha_documento       base_fecha_base,
  n.ncreci_comprobante           base_comprobante_base,
  c.cuotprov_monto               base_monto_base,
  n.ncreci_cotizacion            base_cotizacion_base,
  n.ncreci_situacion             base_situacion
FROM cuotas_proveedores c
INNER JOIN notas_creditos_recibidas n
ON n.ncreci_numero = c.cuotprov_operacion_numero
and n.ncreci_empr_codigo = c.cuotprov_empr_codigo
and n.ncreci_opertipo_codigo = c.cuotprov_opertipo_codigo
and c.cuotprov_movi_codigo = 9 
and n.ncreci_opertipo_codigo = 7 

UNION ALL

SELECT
  c.cuotprov_empr_codigo         base_empr_codigo,
  c.cuotprov_sucu_codigo         base_sucu_codigo,
  c.cuotprov_movi_codigo         base_movi_codigo,
  d.devocomp_prov_codigo         base_prov_codigo,
  d.devocomp_mon_codigo          base_mon_codigo,
  c.cuotprov_secuencia           base_cuotprov_secuencia_base,
  c.cuotprov_opertipo_codigo     base_opertipo_codigo_base,
  c.cuotprov_operacion_numero    base_operacion_numero_base,
  d.devocomp_fecha_documento     base_fecha_base,
  d.devocomp_comprobante         base_comprobante_base,
  c.cuotprov_monto               base_monto_base,
  d.devocomp_cotizacion          base_cotizacion_base,
  d.devocomp_situacion           base_situacion
FROM cuotas_proveedores c
INNER JOIN devoluciones_compras d
ON d.devocomp_numero = c.cuotprov_operacion_numero
and d.devocomp_empr_codigo = c.cuotprov_empr_codigo
and d.devocomp_opertipo_codigo = c.cuotprov_opertipo_codigo
and c.cuotprov_movi_codigo = 3 nc
and d.devocomp_opertipo_codigo = 7 

UNION ALL  

SELECT
  c.cuotprov_empr_codigo                                base_empr_codigo,
  c.cuotprov_sucu_codigo                                base_sucu_codigo,
  c.cuotprov_movi_codigo                                base_movi_codigo,
  d.perssaldinicdeta_pers_codigo                        base_prov_codigo,
  s.perssaldinic_mon_codigo                             base_mon_codigo,
  c.cuotprov_secuencia                                  base_cuotprov_secuencia_base,
  c.cuotprov_opertipo_codigo                            base_opertipo_codigo_base,
  d.perssaldinicdeta_perssaldinic_numero                base_operacion_numero_base,
  s.perssaldinic_fecha                                  base_fecha_base,
  d.perssaldinicdeta_comprobante                        base_comprobante_base,
  d.perssaldinicdeta_saldo_base                         base_monto_base,
  s.perssaldinic_cotizacion                             base_cotizacion_base,
  s.perssaldinic_situacion                              base_situacion
FROM cuotas_proveedores c
INNER JOIN personas_saldos_iniciales_detalles d
on d.perssaldinicdeta_secuencia = c.cuotprov_operacion_numero
and d.perssaldinicdeta_empr_codigo = c.cuotprov_empr_codigo

INNER JOIN personas_saldos_iniciales s
on s.perssaldinic_numero = d.perssaldinicdeta_perssaldinic_numero
and s.perssaldinic_empr_codigo  = d.perssaldinicdeta_empr_codigo
WHERE c.cuotprov_opertipo_codigo IN (41, 17, 2,  7)
and c.cuotprov_opertipo_codigo = c.cuotprov_opertipo_codigo
and c.cuotprov_movi_codigo = 24
```

**Segunda Vista**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE  VIEW proveedores_movimientos_complemento_v AS
SELECT
  0                          complemento_cuotprov_secuencia_complemento,
  p.pago_opertipo_codigo     complemento_opertipo_codigo_complemento,
  p.pago_numero              complemento_operacion_numero_complemento, 
  p.pago_fecha_documento     complemento_fecha_complemento,
  p.pago_recibo_numero       complemento_comprobante_complemento,
  d.pagodeta_cancelacion     complemento_monto_complemento,
  p.pago_cotizacion          complemento_cotizacion_complemento,
  d.pagodeta_cuot_secuencia  complemento_cuotprov_secuencia_origen,
  p.pago_situacion           complemento_situacion 
FROM pagos p
INNER JOIN pagos_detalles d
ON d.pagodeta_pago_numero = p.pago_numero
and d.pagodeta_empr_codigo = p.pago_empr_codigo
and p.pago_opertipo_codigo = 21

UNION ALL

SELECT
  0                          complemento_cuotprov_secuencia_complemento,
  c.cobr_opertipo_codigo     complemento_opertipo_codigo_complemento,
  c.cobr_numero              complemento_operacion_numero_complemento,
  c.cobr_fecha_documento     complemento_fecha_complemento,
  c.cobr_comprobante         complemento_comprobante_complemento,
  d.cobrdeta_cancelacion     complemento_monto_complemento,
  c.cobr_cotizacion          complemento_cotizacion_complemento,
  d.cobrdeta_cuot_secuencia  complemento_cuotprov_secuencia_origen,
  c.cobr_situacion           complemento_situacion 
FROM cobros c
INNER JOIN cobros_detalles d
ON d.cobrdeta_cobr_numero = c.cobr_numero
and d.cobrdeta_empr_codigo = c.cobr_empr_codigo
and c.cobr_opertipo_codigo in (19, 20) 

UNION ALL

SELECT
  d.canccuotprovncantdeta_cuot_secuencia complemento_cuotprov_secuencia_complemento,
  cuo.cuotprov_opertipo_codigo           complemento_opertipo_codigo_complemento,
  cuo.cuotprov_operacion_numero          complemento_operacion_numero_complemento,
  c.canccuotprov_fecha_documento         complemento_fecha_complemento,
  cast(ifnull(ifnull(ifnull(nce.ncreci_comprobante, devo.devocomp_comprobante), anti.antiprov_recibo_numero), c.canccuotprov_numero) as char(50)) complemento_comprobante_complemento, 
  d1.canccuotprovcompdeta_cancelacion     complemento_monto_complemento,
  c.canccuotprov_cotizacion               complemento_cotizacion_complemento,
  d1.canccuotprovcompdeta_cuot_secuencia  complemento_cuotprov_secuencia_origen,
  c.canccuotprov_situacion                complemento_situacion 
FROM cancelaciones_cuotas_proveedores c
INNER JOIN cancelaciones_cuotas_proveedores_nc_ant_detalles d
ON d.canccuotprovncantdeta_canccuotprov_numero = c.canccuotprov_numero
and d.canccuotprovncantdeta_empr_codigo = c.canccuotprov_empr_codigo

LEFT JOIN cancelaciones_cuotas_proveedores_comp_detalles d1
ON d1.canccuotprovcompdeta_canccuotprov_numero = c.canccuotprov_numero
and d1.canccuotprovcompdeta_empr_codigo = c.canccuotprov_empr_codigo
and d1.canccuotprovcompdeta_canccuotprov_numero = d.canccuotprovncantdeta_canccuotprov_numero

INNER JOIN cuotas_proveedores cuo
ON cuo.cuotprov_secuencia = d.canccuotprovncantdeta_cuot_secuencia

LEFT JOIN notas_creditos_recibidas nce 
ON nce.ncreci_numero = cuo.cuotprov_operacion_numero
and nce.ncreci_empr_codigo = cuo.cuotprov_empr_codigo
and nce.ncreci_opertipo_codigo = cuo.cuotprov_opertipo_codigo
and cuo.cuotprov_movi_codigo = 9

LEFT JOIN devoluciones_compras devo 
ON devo.devocomp_numero = cuo.cuotprov_operacion_numero
and devo.devocomp_empr_codigo = cuo.cuotprov_empr_codigo
and devo.devocomp_opertipo_codigo = cuo.cuotprov_opertipo_codigo
and cuo.cuotprov_movi_codigo = 3

LEFT JOIN anticipos_proveedores anti 
ON anti.antiprov_numero = cuo.cuotprov_operacion_numero
and anti.antiprov_empr_codigo = cuo.cuotprov_empr_codigo
and anti.antiprov_opertipo_codigo = cuo.cuotprov_opertipo_codigo

where anti.antiprov_prov_codigo is not null


UNION ALL

SELECT
  d.canccuotprovcompdeta_cuot_secuencia  complemento_cuotprov_secuencia_complemento,
  cuo.cuotprov_opertipo_codigo           complemento_opertipo_codigo_complemento,
  cuo.cuotprov_operacion_numero          complemento_operacion_numero_complemento,
  ifnull(ifnull(comp.comp_fecha_documento, egre.egre_fecha_documento), canccuotprov_fecha_documento) complemento_fecha_complemento, 
  cast(ifnull(ifnull(comp.comp_comprobante, egre.egre_comprobante),c.canccuotprov_numero) as char(50))  complemento_comprobante_complemento,
  d.canccuotprovcompdeta_cancelacion       complemento_monto_complemento,
  c.canccuotprov_cotizacion                complemento_cotizacion_complemento,
  d1.canccuotprovncantdeta_cuot_secuencia  complemento_cuotprov_secuencia_origen,
  c.canccuotprov_situacion                 complemento_situacion
FROM cancelaciones_cuotas_proveedores c
INNER JOIN cancelaciones_cuotas_proveedores_comp_detalles d
ON d.canccuotprovcompdeta_canccuotprov_numero = c.canccuotprov_numero
and d.canccuotprovcompdeta_empr_codigo = c.canccuotprov_empr_codigo

INNER JOIN cancelaciones_cuotas_proveedores_nc_ant_detalles d1
ON d1.canccuotprovncantdeta_canccuotprov_numero = c.canccuotprov_numero
and d1.canccuotprovncantdeta_empr_codigo = c.canccuotprov_empr_codigo
and d1.canccuotprovncantdeta_canccuotprov_numero = d.canccuotprovcompdeta_canccuotprov_numero

INNER JOIN cuotas_proveedores cuo
ON cuo.cuotprov_secuencia = d.canccuotprovcompdeta_cuot_secuencia

LEFT JOIN compras comp
ON comp.comp_numero = cuo.cuotprov_operacion_numero
and comp.comp_empr_codigo = cuo.cuotprov_empr_codigo
AND comp.comp_opertipo_codigo = cuo.cuotprov_opertipo_codigo
and comp.comp_movi_codigo = cuo.cuotprov_movi_codigo

LEFT JOIN egresos egre
ON  egre.egre_numero = cuo.cuotprov_operacion_numero
and egre.egre_empr_codigo = cuo.cuotprov_empr_codigo
and egre.egre_opertipo_codigo = cuo.cuotprov_opertipo_codigo
and egre.egre_movi_codigo = cuo.cuotprov_movi_codigo


UNION ALL


SELECT
  d1.canccuotprovncantdeta_cuot_secuencia  complemento_cuotprov_secuencia_complemento,
  cuo_dev.cuotprov_opertipo_codigo           complemento_opertipo_codigo_complemento,
  cuo_dev.cuotprov_operacion_numero         complemento_operacion_numero_complemento,
  c.canccuotprov_fecha_documento         complemento_fecha_complemento,
  cast(devo.devocomp_comprobante as char(50))  complemento_comprobante_complemento,
  d.canccuotprovcompdeta_cancelacion       complemento_monto_complemento,
  c.canccuotprov_cotizacion                complemento_cotizacion_complemento,
  d.canccuotprovcompdeta_cuot_secuencia  complemento_cuotprov_secuencia_origen,
  c.canccuotprov_situacion                 complemento_situacion -- ¿DUDA?,
FROM cancelaciones_cuotas_proveedores c
INNER JOIN cancelaciones_cuotas_proveedores_comp_detalles d
ON d.canccuotprovcompdeta_canccuotprov_numero = c.canccuotprov_numero
and d.canccuotprovcompdeta_empr_codigo = c.canccuotprov_empr_codigo

INNER JOIN cancelaciones_cuotas_proveedores_nc_ant_detalles d1
ON d1.canccuotprovncantdeta_canccuotprov_numero = c.canccuotprov_numero
and d1.canccuotprovncantdeta_empr_codigo = c.canccuotprov_empr_codigo
and d1.canccuotprovncantdeta_canccuotprov_numero = d.canccuotprovcompdeta_canccuotprov_numero

INNER JOIN cuotas_proveedores cuo
ON cuo.cuotprov_secuencia = d.canccuotprovcompdeta_cuot_secuencia

INNER JOIN cuotas_proveedores cuo_dev
on cuo_dev.cuotprov_secuencia = d1.canccuotprovncantdeta_cuot_secuencia

INNER JOIN devoluciones_compras devo
on cuo_dev.cuotprov_operacion_numero = devo.devocomp_numero
and cuo_dev.cuotprov_opertipo_codigo = devo.devocomp_opertipo_codigo
and cuo_dev.cuotprov_empr_codigo = devo.devocomp_empr_codigo
and cuo_dev.cuotprov_movi_codigo = 3
where c.canccuotprov_situacion = 'VIGENTE'

UNION ALL

SELECT
  d1.canccuotprovncantdeta_cuot_secuencia  complemento_cuotprov_secuencia_complemento,
  cuo_dev.cuotprov_opertipo_codigo           complemento_opertipo_codigo_complemento,
  cuo_dev.cuotprov_operacion_numero          complemento_operacion_numero_complemento,
  c.canccuotprov_fecha_documento         complemento_fecha_complemento,
  cast(devo.ncreci_comprobante as char(50))  complemento_comprobante_complemento,
  d.canccuotprovcompdeta_cancelacion       complemento_monto_complemento,
  c.canccuotprov_cotizacion                complemento_cotizacion_complemento,
  d.canccuotprovcompdeta_cuot_secuencia  complemento_cuotprov_secuencia_origen,
  c.canccuotprov_situacion                 complemento_situacion
FROM cancelaciones_cuotas_proveedores c
INNER JOIN cancelaciones_cuotas_proveedores_comp_detalles d
ON d.canccuotprovcompdeta_canccuotprov_numero = c.canccuotprov_numero
and d.canccuotprovcompdeta_empr_codigo = c.canccuotprov_empr_codigo

INNER JOIN cancelaciones_cuotas_proveedores_nc_ant_detalles d1
ON d1.canccuotprovncantdeta_canccuotprov_numero = c.canccuotprov_numero
and d1.canccuotprovncantdeta_empr_codigo = c.canccuotprov_empr_codigo
and d1.canccuotprovncantdeta_canccuotprov_numero = d.canccuotprovcompdeta_canccuotprov_numero

INNER JOIN cuotas_proveedores cuo
ON cuo.cuotprov_secuencia = d.canccuotprovcompdeta_cuot_secuencia

INNER JOIN cuotas_proveedores cuo_dev
on cuo_dev.cuotprov_secuencia = d1.canccuotprovncantdeta_cuot_secuencia


INNER JOIN notas_creditos_recibidas devo
on cuo_dev.cuotprov_operacion_numero = devo.ncreci_numero
and cuo_dev.cuotprov_opertipo_codigo = devo.ncreci_opertipo_codigo
and cuo_dev.cuotprov_empr_codigo = devo.ncreci_empr_codigo
and cuo_dev.cuotprov_movi_codigo = 9
where c.canccuotprov_situacion = 'VIGENTE'



UNION ALL


SELECT  
  c.cuotprov_secuencia        complemento_cuotprov_secuencia_complemento,
  c.cuotprov_opertipo_codigo  complemento_opertipo_codigo_complemento,
  c.cuotprov_operacion_numero complemento_operacion_numero_complemento,
  nc.ncreci_fecha_documento   complemento_fecha_complemento,
  nc.ncreci_comprobante       complemento_comprobante_complemento,
  d.ncrecifactreladeta_cancelacion_factreci complemento_monto_complemento,
  nc.ncreci_cotizacion complemento_cotizacion_complemento,
  d.ncrecifactreladeta_cuotprov_secuencia_factreci complemento_cuotprov_secuencia_origen,
  nc.ncreci_situacion complemento_situacion
FROM notas_creditos_recibidas_facturas_relacionadas_detalles d
INNER JOIN notas_creditos_recibidas nc
ON nc.ncreci_numero       = d.ncrecifactreladeta_operacion_numero_ncreci
and nc.ncreci_empr_codigo = d.ncrecifactreladeta_empr_codigo
and d.ncrecifactreladeta_movi_codigo_ncreci = 9 -- para diferenciación de registro
INNER JOIN cuotas_proveedores c
on c.cuotprov_opertipo_codigo = nc.ncreci_opertipo_codigo
and c.cuotprov_operacion_numero =  nc.ncreci_numero
and c.cuotprov_movi_codigo = 9
where c.cuotprov_opertipo_codigo = 7
and d.ncrecifactreladeta_saldo_factreci > 0 

UNION ALL 


SELECT  
  c.cuotprov_secuencia          complemento_cuotprov_secuencia_complemento,
  c.cuotprov_opertipo_codigo    complemento_opertipo_codigo_complemento,
  c.cuotprov_operacion_numero   complemento_operacion_numero_complemento,
  nc.devocomp_fecha_documento   complemento_fecha_complemento,
  nc.devocomp_comprobante       complemento_comprobante_complemento,
  d.ncrecifactreladeta_cancelacion_factreci complemento_monto_complemento,
  nc.devocomp_cotizacion complemento_cotizacion_complemento,
  d.ncrecifactreladeta_cuotprov_secuencia_factreci complemento_cuotprov_secuencia_origen,
  nc.devocomp_situacion complemento_situacion
FROM notas_creditos_recibidas_facturas_relacionadas_detalles d
INNER JOIN devoluciones_compras nc
ON nc.devocomp_numero       = d.ncrecifactreladeta_operacion_numero_ncreci
and nc.devocomp_empr_codigo = d.ncrecifactreladeta_empr_codigo
and d.ncrecifactreladeta_movi_codigo_ncreci = 3 
INNER JOIN cuotas_proveedores c
on c.cuotprov_opertipo_codigo = nc.devocomp_opertipo_codigo
and c.cuotprov_operacion_numero =  nc.devocomp_numero
and c.cuotprov_movi_codigo = 3 -
where c.cuotprov_opertipo_codigo = 7 
AND d.ncrecifactreladeta_saldo_base_factreci > 0  

UNION ALL


SELECT
  d.ncrecifactreladeta_cuotprov_secuencia_factreci       complemento_cuotprov_secuencia_complemento,
  c.cuotprov_opertipo_codigo  complemento_opertipo_codigo_complemento,
  c.cuotprov_operacion_numero complemento_operacion_numero_complemento,
  comp.comp_fecha_documento   complemento_fecha_complemento,
  comp.comp_comprobante       complemento_comprobante_complemento,
  d.ncrecifactreladeta_cancelacion_factreci complemento_monto_complemento,
  comp.comp_cotizacion complemento_cotizacion_complemento,
  cd.cuotprov_secuencia  complemento_cuotprov_secuencia_origen,
  comp.comp_situacion   complemento_situacion
FROM notas_creditos_recibidas_facturas_relacionadas_detalles d

INNER JOIN devoluciones_compras nc
ON nc.devocomp_numero       = d.ncrecifactreladeta_operacion_numero_ncreci
and nc.devocomp_empr_codigo = d.ncrecifactreladeta_empr_codigo
and d.ncrecifactreladeta_movi_codigo_ncreci = 3


INNER JOIN compras comp
on comp.comp_numero = d.ncrecifactreladeta_operacion_numero_factreci
and comp.comp_empr_codigo = d.ncrecifactreladeta_empr_codigo
and comp.comp_movi_codigo = d.ncrecifactreladeta_movi_codigo_factreci 


INNER JOIN cuotas_proveedores c
on c.cuotprov_secuencia = d.ncrecifactreladeta_cuotprov_secuencia_factreci


INNER JOIN cuotas_proveedores cd
on cd.cuotprov_opertipo_codigo = nc.devocomp_opertipo_codigo
and cd.cuotprov_operacion_numero =  nc.devocomp_numero
and cd.cuotprov_movi_codigo = 3


where cd.cuotprov_opertipo_codigo = 7 
and d.ncrecifactreladeta_saldo_factreci > 0

UNION ALL 


SELECT
  c.cuotprov_secuencia        complemento_cuotprov_secuencia_complemento,
  c.cuotprov_opertipo_codigo  complemento_opertipo_codigo_complemento,
  c.cuotprov_operacion_numero complemento_operacion_numero_complemento,
  comp.comp_fecha_documento   complemento_fecha_complemento,
  comp.comp_comprobante       complemento_comprobante_complemento,
  d.ncrecifactreladeta_cancelacion_factreci complemento_monto_complemento,
  comp.comp_cotizacion complemento_cotizacion_complemento,
  cnc.cuotprov_secuencia complemento_cuotprov_secuencia_origen,
  comp.comp_situacion complemento_situacion
FROM notas_creditos_recibidas_facturas_relacionadas_detalles d
INNER JOIN notas_creditos_recibidas nc
ON nc.ncreci_numero       = d.ncrecifactreladeta_operacion_numero_ncreci
and nc.ncreci_empr_codigo = d.ncrecifactreladeta_empr_codigo
and d.ncrecifactreladeta_movi_codigo_ncreci = 9 


INNER JOIN compras comp 
on comp.comp_numero = d.ncrecifactreladeta_operacion_numero_factreci
and comp.comp_empr_codigo = d.ncrecifactreladeta_empr_codigo
and comp.comp_movi_codigo = d.ncrecifactreladeta_movi_codigo_factreci 

INNER JOIN cuotas_proveedores c  
on c.cuotprov_opertipo_codigo = d.ncrecifactreladeta_opertipo_codigo_factreci
and c.cuotprov_operacion_numero =  d.ncrecifactreladeta_operacion_numero_factreci
and c.cuotprov_movi_codigo in (1)

INNER JOIN cuotas_proveedores cnc 
ON cnc.cuotprov_opertipo_codigo = nc.ncreci_opertipo_codigo
and cnc.cuotprov_movi_codigo = 9
and cnc.cuotprov_operacion_numero = nc.ncreci_numero
and cnc.cuotprov_empr_codigo = nc.ncreci_empr_codigo
where c.cuotprov_opertipo_codigo in (2)
and d.ncrecifactreladeta_saldo_factreci > 0


UNION ALL


SELECT
  c.cuotprov_secuencia        complemento_cuotprov_secuencia_complemento, 
  c.cuotprov_opertipo_codigo  complemento_opertipo_codigo_complemento,
  c.cuotprov_operacion_numero complemento_operacion_numero_complemento,
  comp.egre_fecha_documento   complemento_fecha_complemento,
  comp.egre_comprobante       complemento_comprobante_complemento,
  d.ncrecifactreladeta_cancelacion_factreci complemento_monto_complemento,
  comp.egre_cotizacion complemento_cotizacion_complemento,
  cnc.cuotprov_secuencia complemento_cuotprov_secuencia_origen,
  comp.egre_situacion complemento_situacion
FROM notas_creditos_recibidas_facturas_relacionadas_detalles d
INNER JOIN notas_creditos_recibidas nc
ON nc.ncreci_numero       = d.ncrecifactreladeta_operacion_numero_ncreci
and nc.ncreci_empr_codigo = d.ncrecifactreladeta_empr_codigo
and d.ncrecifactreladeta_movi_codigo_ncreci = 9 


INNER JOIN egresos comp 
on comp.egre_numero = d.ncrecifactreladeta_operacion_numero_factreci
and comp.egre_empr_codigo = d.ncrecifactreladeta_empr_codigo
and comp.egre_movi_codigo = d.ncrecifactreladeta_movi_codigo_factreci 

INNER JOIN cuotas_proveedores c  
on c.cuotprov_opertipo_codigo = d.ncrecifactreladeta_opertipo_codigo_factreci
and c.cuotprov_operacion_numero =  d.ncrecifactreladeta_operacion_numero_factreci
and c.cuotprov_movi_codigo in (7) 

INNER JOIN cuotas_proveedores cnc
ON cnc.cuotprov_opertipo_codigo = nc.ncreci_opertipo_codigo
and cnc.cuotprov_movi_codigo = 9
and cnc.cuotprov_operacion_numero = nc.ncreci_numero
and cnc.cuotprov_empr_codigo = nc.ncreci_empr_codigo
where c.cuotprov_opertipo_codigo in (2)
```

**Tercera Vista**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW proveedores_movimientos_v AS
SELECT base_empr_codigo provmovi_empr_codigo,
       base_sucu_codigo provmovi_sucu_codigo,
       base_movi_codigo provmovi_movi_codigo, 
       base_prov_codigo provmovi_prov_codigo,
       base_mon_codigo  provmovi_mon_codigo,
       base_cuotprov_secuencia_base provmovi_cuotprov_secuencia_base,
       base_opertipo_codigo_base provmovi_opertipo_codigo_base,
       base_operacion_numero_base provmovi_operacion_numero_base,
       base_fecha_base provmovi_fecha_base,
       base_comprobante_base provmovi_comprobante_base,
       base_monto_base provmovi_monto_base,
       base_cotizacion_base provmovi_cotizacion_base,
       base_situacion provmovi_base_situacion,
       c.complemento_cuotprov_secuencia_complemento   provmovi_cuotprov_secuencia_complemento,
       c.complemento_opertipo_codigo_complemento      provmovi_opertipo_codigo_complemento,
       c.complemento_operacion_numero_complemento     provmovi_operacion_numero_complemento,
       c.complemento_fecha_complemento                provmovi_fecha_complemento,
       c.complemento_comprobante_complemento          provmovi_comprobante_complemento,
       c.complemento_monto_complemento                provmovi_monto_complemento,
       c.complemento_cotizacion_complemento           provmovi_cotizacion_complemento,
       ifnull(c.complemento_situacion, b.base_situacion)     provmovi_situacion
FROM proveedores_movimientos_base_v b
LEFT JOIN proveedores_movimientos_complemento_v c
ON c.complemento_cuotprov_secuencia_origen = b.base_cuotprov_secuencia_base
and c.complemento_situacion = 'VIGENTE';
```

Ejecutando la primera y la segunda vista por separado la velocidad de respuesta es muy rápida, pero ejecutando la última vista la velocidad no es tan buena. Estoy trabajando con apenas 50.000 registros.

Las tablas y los campos involucrados están bien indexados.

El explain de la consulta a la tercera vista es el siguiente (Como imagen porque 
 no entra como texto):
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Intenta hacerle un EXPLAIN a la vista para ver en que está tardandose, creo que hace por cada vista se vuelve a ejecutar la vista anterior, tu problema no se solucionaría con un CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE? de tus primeras 2 vistas ?

Comment: Creando la tabla temporal con un indice para las dos primeras vistas el resultado para la tercera vista es bastante rápida, pero, con el volcado de datos a la tabla temporal el tiempo total es casi lo mismo.

Comment: Y con el EXPLAIN de tu última vista que te dice, puedes copiar el resultado por favor.

Comment: que pasa si creas tablas temporales con indices para las dos primeras vistas? no entiendo mucho ese explain, no es mi especialidad mysql, pero pensandolo en agnostico, estaria haciendo un full scan para unir las dos vistas, por cada registro.

Comment: @gbianchi, por el momento esa metodología estoy implementando para mejorar el rendimiento, pero cuando existen gran cantidad de registros el tiempo de inserción a las tablas temporales equivale casi a la consulta global.

Comment: entonces hay un problema con los querys que provoca eso.. habria que desglosar cada query punto por punto para hacer que cada uno funcione mas rapido. esto es comun con muchos datos, y para eso se usan tablas intermedias y vistas materializadas con indices para evitar estos problemas.

Comment: Lamentablemente que yo sepa mysql no posee vistas materializadas. Las dos primeras vistas por separado son rápidas, pero uniendo en una tercera vista derivada resulta lenta, me parece raro. No quiero decir que al mysql le resulta complicado acceder a los indices desde una vista derivada.

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir las sentencias para crear las tablas ? Por favor

Comment: ¿El EXPLAIN que muestras es de la consulta: `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` ? Aparecen al principio dos tablas derivadas que no comprendo de donde salen.

Comment: El EXPLAIN que se muestra es de la consulta realizada a la tercera vista, que es la derivada de la primera y la segunda, por eso se visualiza de esa manera.

Comment: ¿Hay algún motivo por el que **debas** usar `vistas`? Si puedes prescindir de ellas, lo mejor sería hacer una sola consulta que una todas las tablas que intervienen en las tres vistas. Si los índices están optimizados no vas a tener problemas, mientras que al usar vistas, generalmente vas a tener problemas de índices y el código funcionará más lento.

Comment: ¿Podrías poner los create table e indicar las relaciones entre tablas para porder hacer algunas pruebas? hay algunas cosas que no me convencen a priori pero sin ver las tablas no puedo decir mucho mas.

Answer (score 0):

El `IN (41, 17, 2,  7)` y el `in (7)` está matando la query. Por otro lado los *`= numero fijo`* deberías ponerlo como primera condición del join para que filtre más rápido.

Comment: Muchas gracias por su respuesta, el uso del *in* puede que reduzca un poco el rendimiento, pero como expliqué, ejecutando consultas individuales a las dos primeras vistas la respuesta es prácticamente normal. Tu sugerencia es útil para optimizar las dos primeras vistas, pero mi problema es la derivada de las dos, es decir, la tercera vista que tarda y aparentemente es porque no puede acceder a los índices si se usa uniones para crear las vistas base. Saludos cordiales!

Comment: Me alegro que te haya sido útil. Se me ocurre una solución para no romper los indices de las tablas. Básicamente deberías crear un Stored Procedure, en dicho stored procedure vas a volcar los datos de las 3 Querys en 3 tablas separadas (temporales o no). Luego haces un union del select de dichas 3 tablas. De esta forma se realiza el filtrado de datos usando los indices y el unión se realiza sobre tablas que otros usuarios no estén usando y que ademas tengan menos datos. Proba medir los tiempos, de seguro son mas cortos. Saludos.